# I have created one workflow rule to populate one field(workflow field update) if it is blank

Tags: workflow

I have created one workflow rule to populate one field(workflow field update)  if it is blank, but it is getting overridden with WFR even if I am manually entering data in that field.
Workflow rule:
[image]
Workflow Field Update:
[image]
I am not able to understand I am entered criteria to check if Street field is null, then only it should trigger. Why it is overriding values that I have entered manually in street field with Workflow field update.

Comment: Do you have some other workflow or process builder that is populating the field?

Comment: No, But my issue was  resolved when in rule criteria I changed from normal condition to formulae AND 
( 
RecordType.DeveloperName="USCan_Sample_Request", 
ISBLANK( USCan_Street__c ) 
)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was  resolved when in rule criteria I changed from normal condition to formulae AND ( RecordType.DeveloperName="USCan_Sample_Request", ISBLANK( USCan_Street__c ) )